# Merge two factor columns in R

Tags: r, merge

Hi I am having trouble with something in R. I'm trying to merge (combine?) two (factor) columns in a data frame. For each row, there is a value in only one of the columns and I want to combine them so that all the rows have a value. As a simplified example, suppose I've run the following code: `df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b", " ", " "), y=c(" ", " ", "q", " "), z=c(" ", " ", " ", "p"))`, I get the following data frame

```
    x   y
1   a   
2   b        
3       q
```

After the x and y columns are merged, The result would be

```
  x y merged
1 a        a
2 b        b
3   q      q
```

I have tried using `df$merged = ifelse(df$x == " ", df$y, df$x)`, but it gives me these numbers. Any idea what they mean?

```
  x y merged
1 a        2
2 b        3
3   q      2
```

All the other helpful information I have come across works well with numbers, but not characters. Am I on the right track with what I have tried so far?

It seems like such a simple problem but I have not been able to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks all.

Comment: Please make sure that your input df (four rows, three cols) matches with the output (three rows, two cols).

Answer (score 2):

In your example dataset, there were three columns.  The below approach could be used when there are multiple columns.  (Here, I assumed that you have only a single "value" in each row)

```
df$merged <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df),max.col(df!=' ', 'first'))]
df
#  x y z merged
#1 a          a
#2 b          b
#3   q        q
#4     p      p
```

Or a loop method would be:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) x[x!=' '])
#[1] "a" "b" "q" "p"
```

If there are more than one "value" per row, you can `paste` the values together. `toString` is a wrapper for `paste(., collapse=", ")`

```
apply(df,1, function(x) toString(x[x!=' ']))
```

Or you could `melt` the dataset and then use `aggregate` to `paste` the values

```
library(reshape2)
aggregate(value~Var1, subset(melt(as.matrix(df)), value!= ' '), 
                      toString)$value
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b", " ", " "), y=c(" ", " ", "q", " "), 
                z=c(" ", " ", " ", "p"))
```

Comment: I love your answer. But I believe  your answer assumes that its a dataframe with only X columns and they all should be merged. Can you please show a modified version of your first example to show how I can merge starting from column X to column Z using indexes perhaps?

Comment: @JimBeam In that case subset only for those columns i.e. `df[c("X", "Z")][cbind(1:nrow(df),max.col(df[c("X", "Z")]!=' ', 'first'))]` or the numeric index to subset the columns.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the numbers appear is because your data.frame contains `factors`:
Check `?data.frame` and especially the argument `stringsAsFactors`

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b", " ", " "), 
                 y=c(" ", " ", "q", " "), 
                 z=c(" ", " ", " ", "p"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$merged = ifelse(df$x == " ", df$y, df$x)
```

Side note: using space `" "` is not really recommended for holes in your data.frame. Use instead `NA`.