# Merging two factor/character columns into one column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I have the below dataset that is built from

```
help <- data.frame(var1 = c("red", NA, NA, NA, "red", "orange"),
               var2 = c(NA, "lightred", "blue", "lightred", NA, NA))

    var1     var2
1    red     <NA>
2   <NA> lightred
3   <NA>     blue
4   <NA> lightred
5    red     <NA>
6 orange     <NA>
```

And I am stuck trying to make a new variable, `newvar` that simply merges the factor variables into one new column. I am hoping to get output as follows

```
    var1     var2   newvar
1    red     <NA>    red
2   <NA> lightred    lightred
3   <NA>     blue    blue
4   <NA> lightred    lightred
5    red     <NA>    red
6 orange     <NA>    orange
```

Here was my attempt based on other threads here

```
help$newvar = ifelse(help$var1 == "", help$var2, help$var1)
```

When the variables are factors, the `newvar` are numbers, which makes sense, but only variables from `var1` move to `newvar`. When character, again only the characters from `var1` move to `newvar`.

I know similar questions have been asked, but the answers didn't seem to fix this issue. [Merge two factor columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145525/merge-two-factor-columns-in-r)

Is there a way to do this in dplyr too? I'll take whatever solution I can get, just curious.

Comment: I don't see any blanks in your `var1`, I see missing values. Use `is.na(help$var1)` instead of `help$var1 == ""`.

Comment: Another option `apply(help, 1, na.omit)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any blanks in your var1, I see missing values. Use `is.na(help$var1)` instead of `help$var1 == ""`

You'll also want to convert to character since you have factors with different levels.

```
help$newvar = ifelse(is.na(help$var1), as.character(help$var2), as.character(help$var1))
```

Of course you can use `dplyr`, you're just creating a column

```
help = mutate(help, newvar = ifelse(is.na(var1), as.character(var2), as.character(var1)))
```

In SQL, this operation is called *coalesce*. You might be interested in [How to implement coalesce efficiently in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253820/903061)

Comment: Ok great. I see what you mean with the is.na... I was messing with both "" and NA when I built this df for the example. When I leave it as a factor, that code gives me numbers for `newvar` and when i convert to character it works well

Comment: Also thank you for the resource regarding coalescing

Comment: Thanks, edited in the character conversion. The real lesson here is that a blank is different than a missing value.

Comment: The coalesce answer predates `tidyr`, but the other answer with `tidyr::unite` is probably more convenient.

Comment: Why can't you just use `transform` from base R instead of `dplyr::mutate`? It's exactly the same syntax

Comment: @DavidArenburg Just giving OP what OP asks for: "Is there a way to do this in dplyr too?" I hope my answer illustrates that you're just adding a column however you do it---that's why I started with `help$newvar = ...`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)

help[] <- lapply(help, as.character)
help[is.na(help)] <- ''
unite(help, new, var1:var2, sep='', remove=F)

#       new   var1     var2
#1      red    red         
#2 lightred        lightred
#3     blue            blue
#4 lightred        lightred
#5      red    red         
#6   orange orange
```

Or a base `R` hack:

```
transform(help, new = gsub('NA','',do.call(paste0, help))

#    var1     var2      new
#1    red     <NA>      red
#2   <NA> lightred lightred
#3   <NA>     blue     blue
#4   <NA> lightred lightred
#5    red     <NA>      red
#6 orange     <NA>   orange
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of just subsetting the non- `NA`s values out of `help`

```
t(help)[t(!is.na(help))]
## [1] "red"      "lightred" "blue"     "lightred" "red"      "orange"
```

The need in `t` is because the subsetting in R is been done by column instead by row

Answer (score 1):

In this case the `sqldf` package comes in handy to use, as Gregor pointed out, the function coalesce:

```
 library(sqldf)
 help$newvar <- sqldf("select coalesce(var1, var2) newvar from help")
```

Output:

```
    var1     var2   newvar
1    red     <NA>      red
2   <NA> lightred lightred
3   <NA>     blue     blue
4   <NA> lightred lightred
5    red     <NA>      red
6 orange     <NA>   orange
```

Comment: or perhaps `help <- sqldf("select *, coalesce(var1, var2) newvar from help")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you for the useful comment